# How to use Clipboard in C# services?

Tags: c#, windows-services, clipboard

1. Keep in mind i am using services not Windows Form App.
2. When I try to use System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText(); my code
   don't go to next step.
3. means System.Windows.Forms Controls are deprecated
4. I am Trying to get copied text from Clipboard and change the text then set back to clipboard.
5. Please Help me.

below is my code

```
 public void working()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            // Get text from clipboard 
             string clipboardtext = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText();

            string path = "c:\\sample.txt";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                
                writer.WriteLine(string.Format("Clip Board Test " + "-" + " " + "Windows Service is called on " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm:ss") + ""));
                writer.Close();
                System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject("Hello ClipBoard");
            }
            Thread.Sleep(ScheduleTime * 6000);
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you trying to work with user's clipboard, then I'm afraid that you will out of luck here - the clipboard is made per-user and the service is working under the dedicated account, other then 'normal' user. But I will be happy to be mistaken here.

Comment: actually i am trying for localsystem not for particular user.

Comment: I cannot even understand what use case can be for such service, but can say definitely - what you trying to do is weird and impossible.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer actually above problem is applicable in windows form but why not in C# Services?

Comment: code has not error but logically its not working.

Comment: There is a big difference between WinForms and a Windows Service

Comment: Yes, you are right but I want how to implement windows form logic in windows services is there any possibility to make it a reality?

Answer (score 2):

Windows service is not running in same "scope" as your user GUI, it cannot access to your clipboard or key stroke or anything you do. Services are useful, because they can run without logged user or under different user.

Services are not allowed to access your keystrokes or clipboard also for security reasons.

Comment: *"Services are not allowed to access your keystrokes or clipboard also for security reasons."* - That's bogus. A service can call [`CreateProcessAsUserW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) and run in *any* user session, gaining immediate access to user input or that user's clipboard data, if it so chooses. Security is established by requiring permissions when *installing* a service. Once a service is installed, it can do pretty much whatever.